# Powershell Split function is broken

Tags: powershell, loops, split

I'm trying to get from this file ->

File 1:

```
Datum;Zeit;mp380_rdh_f2_o;mp383_rlf_f2_o;mp363_rdh_f3;mp362_rlf_f3;mp604_rdh_sitz;mp607_rdh_sitz;mp611_rlf_sitz;mp_358_1_rdl;mp_359_1_rdl;MP520_620_rdl;plf_dichtfl
10_03_2023;08_22_59;0.222;0.231;0.235;0.581;0.266;0.000;0.000;8.937;0.000
```

to this format ->
File 2:

```
Datum;10_03_2023
Zeit;08_22_59
mp380_rdh_f2_o;0.222
mp383_rlf_f2_o;0.231
mp363_rdh_f3;0.231
mp362_rlf_f3;0.235
mp604_rdh_sitz;0.581
mp607_rdh_sitz;0.266
mp611_rlf_sitz;0.000
mp_358_1_rdl;0.000
mp_359_1_rdl;8.937
MP520_620_rdl;0.000
plf_dichtfl
```

I tried to convert the previous file to the new file, but the ValueSplit doesn't work. I get the first array of the ValueLine but it doesn't add the remaining portion of the ValueLine.

Code:

```
        
        $file = Get-Content $SeeFile1

        $SplitCounter = 0

        $HeaderLine = $file[0]
        $HeaderSplit = $HeaderLine -split ";"
        $LengthSplit = $HeaderSplit.Length

        for ($i3 = 1; $i3 -le $LengthSplit; $i3++) {

            $TempCMD = "$" + "file[" + $i3 + "]"
            $ValueLine = $TempCMD | iex
            $ValueSplit = $ValueSplit -split ";"

            $Var1 = $HeaderSplit[$SplitCounter]
            $Var2 = $ValueSplit[$SplitCounter]

            $MergedLine = "$Var1"+ ";" + "$Var2"
            $MergedLine | Out-File -FilePath $MainFile -Append

            $SplitCounter++

        }
```

Here is the output of the $MainFile:

```
Datum;10_03_2023

Zeit;

mp380_rdh_f2_o;

mp383_rlf_f2_o;

mp363_rdh_f3;

mp362_rlf_f3;

mp604_rdh_sitz;

mp607_rdh_sitz;

mp611_rlf_sitz;

mp_358_1_rdl;

mp_359_1_rdl;

MP520_620_rdl;

plf_dichtfl;
```

Now you can see $Var2 only in the first line and the other $Var2 variable are not implemented there. How can I fix that?

After long research I think that the ValueSplit doesn't work properly. I need another solution to get a result but right now I don't know what to do.

Comment: Did you really needed to `$TempCMD | iex` ? :'(

Comment: I think I don't need it. I thought in a for loop it's better to make a TempCMD to make sure that the LengthSplit is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this can be simplified by using `Import-Csv` and and then joining all property names with their corresponding property value by a semi-colon:

```bash
Import-Csv path\to\input.csv -Delimiter ';' | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($prop in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
        $prop.Name, $prop.Value -join ';'
    }
} | Set-Content path\to\output.txt
```